# Invalid input type for c_char ctypes in python

Tags: python, c, header, ctypes

In my C header file I have:

```
long TEST_API test( 
            _IN____ const char arg1,
            _INOUT_ char arg2[512]
    );
```

I have imported `ctypes` in my python code and I am passing "`kcOpCode`" and "`szXMLAdditionalParameters`" to `eftUtility` function as following:

```
utilityXml_bytes = bytearray(b'<xml><test>20</test></xml>')
utilityXMLparams = (ctypes.c_byte*512)(*utilityXml_bytes)

def test():
    eftUtilityRes = lib.test("s", utilityXMLparams)
    if (eftUtilityRes == 10):
        "success"
    elif(eftUtilityRes == -10):
        "type 2 error"
    else:
        "type 3 error"
```

But I keep getting invalid input type error for "`arg1`". what am I doing wrong here? could it be encoding problem? am I actually passing `s` to my function?

Comment: In ctype, you defined `szXMLAdditionalParameters", c_byte*512`, but in your c header, `char szXMLAdditionalParameters[513]`. Looks like an off by one error?

Comment: sorry , I have changed that still same issue.

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: I am getting this message : 'module' object has no attribute 'CONST'

Comment: Just a long shot. Try to use `ctypes.c_byte(ord("s")) `

Comment: FYI, the compiled code for `test` handles the second argument as `char *arg2`. C arrays are passed as pointers. If you printed `sizeof arg2` in `test` it would return 4 or 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your function is `(const char arg1 ... )` so you must pass a char as first argument and not a *character*. That means a byte and not a single char string. To test it I wrote my lib

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(const char v)
{
    printf("Hello, I'm a shared library %c\n",v);
}
```

And compile it by

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

And now call it by python console:

My python script is:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libfoo.so")
>>> a=lib.foo(ord("s"))
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo("s")
Hello, I'm a shared library D
>>> a=lib.foo(b"s")
Hello, I'm a shared library D
```

It is clear that what you need is `ord("s")`.

---

One more thing: it is just a guess but maybe the error that you read came from the library that read an incorrect char as first argument.

---

Follow a lot of edits where we can see how many wrong assumptions or silly errors we can do if we don't use a correct cast by use `ctypes` to call a C library function. Now what I wrote above it was useful just to understand where the issue was but the real production code that should work either in Python 2 and Python 3 should declare the correct function interface and use `b"s"` as argument:

```
>>> lib.foo.argtypes = (c_char,)
>>> lib.foo.restype = None
>>> lib.foo(b"s") 
Hello, I'm a shared library s
```

---

Just for the record:

**[EDIT]**

As @eryksun has correctly pointed me in the comments it is very unsafe call C function without use a correct cast: it is like in C don't use a prototype and everything become `int`. So if you don't set function `argtype` is better use explicit cast like:

```
>>> a=lib.foo(c_char(ord("s"))) #Work Just on Python 3
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo(c_char("s")) # Just Python 2.7
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo(c_char(b"s")) # Python 2 and 3
Hello, I'm a shared library s
```

**[EDIT]**

Follow from your comment: you can also hardcode `ord("s")` by use either `105` or hex value `0x73`

```
>>> a=lib.foo(105)
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo(0x73)
Hello, I'm a shared library s
```

**[EDIT]**

As @Dunes pointed out there is a way to tell to python how do that conversion implicitly by `lib.foo.argtypes = (c_char,)`. But how you build your char by `b"s"` or simply `"s"` doesn't mater (on python 2.7).

```
>>> lib.foo.argtypes = (c_char,)
>>> a=lib.foo(b"s") 
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo("s")  #Python 2.7
Hello, I'm a shared library s
```

In Python 3 use `b"s"` if you specify `argtypes` is mandatory:

```
>>> lib.foo.argtypes = (c_char,)
>>> a=lib.foo(b"s") 
Hello, I'm a shared library s
>>> a=lib.foo("s")  #Python 3.4
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used Hex value of "s"---> 0x73 and everything worked fine. Please add this to your answer for others who may come up with the same issue.

Comment: The `b` prefix is for compatibility with Python 3. It's nice to provide an answer that works in both versions, where possible.

Comment: @eryksun You got a point here. I forgot to try it both 2.7 and 3.x. I'll update my answer. Anyway the `b` prefix doesn't concern the original issue where there is any mention about `TypeError` exceptions.

Comment: If you're not setting `argtypes` (but please do this for type safety in general), I recommend calling `c_char` instead of `ord`. The latter would quietly return an ordinal greater than 255 for a unicode character, which ctypes would quietly pass as a C `int`. It's much cleaner to raise a `TypeError` for a unicode character, which `c_char` does.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks you your note. Just for the record [ctype documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#return-types) make my same mistake :)

Comment: That example was carried over from the 2.x docs (e.g. [Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/ctypes-return-types.html) from 2006), first written back when working with byte strings was the norm.

Comment: @eryksun You are right ... My was just a joke to note that the official documentation doesn't take in account these relevant points. I'm very glad to take in account your observation: I learn a lot by your comments.

Comment: `c_char` takes a single-character byte string, e.g. `c_char(b"s")` works in Python 2 and 3.  Your example with `c_char(ord("s"))` is an error.

Comment: @eryksun are you sure? I'd tried it before write. Now I cannot test it, I 'll check it later.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. `c_char._type_ == 'c'`, for which the corresponding `setfunc` is [`c_set`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1146) (2.7.9 source link).

Comment: @eryksun `c_char(ord("s"))` return `c_char(b's')` in python 3 and raise exception in python 2.7. I-ll fix it ASAP

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not stating that the first arg is a byte string -- `b's'` vs `'s'`. eg.

```
eftUtilityRes = lib.eftUtility(b"s", utilityXMLparams)
```

You also need to tell ctypes what arguments the function takes. Sometimes there is ambiguity to how a python object should be converted. In your case, is a single character string meant to be interpreted as `char` or `char*` (both of which would be valid interpretations).

```
lib.eftUtility.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char, ctypes.c_char_p)
```

In addition your `Structure` is unused and un-needed, and your way of creating a mutable byte array is long-winded. The following is all that is needed.

```
xml_data = b'<xml><DisplayWidthInCharacters>20</DisplayWidthInCharacters><JournalKeepDurationInDays>30</JournalKeepDurationInDays></xml>'
utilityXml = ctypes.create_string_buffer(xml_data, 512) 

def eftUtilityPepper():
    eftUtilityRes = lib.eftUtility(b"s", utilityXml)
    if (eftUtilityRes == 10):
        "success"
    elif(eftUtilityRes == -10):
        "type 2 error"
    else:
        "type 3 error"
```

Comment: Totally forgot a step I missed out. You need to tell ctypes the parameters that the function takes so it knows how to convert the given python objects.

Comment: If `test("s", utilityXMLparams)` raises an `ArgumentError`, then `test.argtypes` is already defined, because passing strings (as `const char *`) or integers (as `int`) works without defining `argtypes`.

Comment: @Dunes You wrote the only thing that mater in your answer just after read in my answer the evidence of what you wrote doesn't work and it was not related to the question. IMHO do it without any credit is not really ethic.